# Matrix Formation in python

Tags: python

enter your code:

```
matrix=[]
n,m=input().split()
p=int(n)
q=int(m)
c=1
for i in range(p):
    l=[]
    for j in range(q):
        l.append(c)
        c=c+1
    matrix.append(l)
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        print(matrix[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

I'm not able to get the correct output?

Compilation and test case answer

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to include desired output and current output as *text*, not as an image

Comment: There is a space between the last digit and `\n` char. That may be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
matrix=[]
n,m=input().split()
p=int(n)
q=int(m)
c=1
for i in range(p):
    l=[]
    for j in range(q):
        l.append(c)
        c=c+1
    matrix.append(l)
for i in range(p):
    for j in range(q):
        if j == q-1 and not i == p-1:
            print(matrix[i][j],end=r"\n")
        else:
            print(matrix[i][j],end=r" ")
    print()
```

I changed the print command if your are at the last line. The r in r"\n" makes it a so called raw string, so the \n will not be read as a new line character.

in:

```
3 6
```

Out:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6\n
7 8 9 10 11 12\n
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: Sir again i am ending with the same output result

Comment: I included the input and output. What exactly is wrong with it? For me it looks like the output in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

def matrix(r,c):
  count=1
  mat=[]
  for i in range(r):
    l=[]
    for j in range(c):
      l.append(count)
      count=count+1
    mat.append(l)

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
      if i
      elif i==r-1 and j==c-1:
        print(mat[i][j],end='',sep='')
      else:
        print(mat[i][j],end=' ')

```
if(i<r-1):
  print(end='\n')
```

a,b=map(int,input().split())
matrix(a,b)

Comment: Please format you code properly and add a minimal explanation of your answer.